# How to convert a GoogleJsonResponseException into a JSONObject in android/java?

Tags: java, android, exception, json, jsonobjectrequest

In my android app, I am handling GoogleJsonResponseException, and depending on its ResultCode and message I should have different code.

```
try {
            //type method here

        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException j) {


            int satusCode = j.getStatusCode();
            String message = getMessageCode(j.toString());}
```

Where getMessage(String s) is a method that returns the exception in this String form:

```
{
"code": 409,
"errors": [
    {
        "domain": "global",
        "message": "Error message",
        "reason": "conflict"
    }
],
"message": "Error message"}
```

And i need the data inside "message". So is there a way I could change this string into a JSONObject or make convert the GoogleJsonResponse exception from the beginning to a JSONObject? Or should I parse the string manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONObject has a constructor that accepts a string. Have you tried that?

Otherwise, [reading the documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/json/GoogleJsonResponseException), I see

```
j.getDetails().getMessage()
```

And since it wasn't clear which message field you wanted, here's the nested one.

```
j.getDetails().getErrors().get(0).getMessage();
```

Comment: Yes the constructor didn't work in my case, but your second suggestion worked thanks! And just to note, I have tried j.getMessage() but that retuns the string in the form of json that I have posted above, which is why I didn't use it.